# Circular dependency while calculating column

Tags: powerbi

I have a single table of data named RDSLPDSL. I am trying to calculate two columns based on two measures I am creating from the table.

```
Count of RDSL Marker for 1 = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNT('RDSLPDSL'[RDSL Marker]),
    'RDSLPDSL'[RDSL Marker] IN { 1 }
)
```

I am using the above code as a measure to look for values only with 1 in it in the RDSL Marker column.

```
RDSL % = DIVIDE([Count of RDSL Marker for 1], COUNTROWS(RDSLPDSL))
```

Then I created a column using the above code to divide the rows with 1 by the total number of rows in the table.

I am doing the same for another column with PDSL. It is as follows:

```
Count of PDSL Marker for 1 = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNT('RDSLPDSL'[PDSL Marker]),
    'RDSLPDSL'[PDSL Marker] IN { 1 }
)

PDSL % = DIVIDE([Count of PDSL Marker for 1], COUNTROWS(RDSLPDSL))
```

But when I do this calculation, I am getting an error for circular dependency detected and not getting the final output even though the same code worked for the previous column.

I tried COUNTAX directly instead of using CALCULATE but that brings up the same error too.
I also tried using measures instead of custom column which seems to remove the error but the output is not what I expect and is incorrect.

Any help for the same would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is it a single table of data?

Comment: Yes, single table of data